# ¿Cómo trabajar con directorios con caracteres acentuados en su ruta en QT?

Tags: qt

Tengo un fragmento de código que explora un directorio recursivamente buscando ficheros con determinada extensión, y guarda sus rutas para posteriormente trabajar sobre ellos, pero el programa me presenta un problema cuando la ruta contiene caracteres acentuados.

Este es el código para escanear:

```
void drivexp::scan(QStringList& parameters)
{
    if(m_dir.isEmpty())
    m_dir = ui->lineEdit->text();
    m_files.clear();
    QDirIterator it(m_dir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    QString directory;

    int j=0;
    int k=0;

    do {
        directory = it.next();

        if(it.fileInfo().isFile()){
            j++;
            QString ext = it.fileInfo().suffix().toLower();
            if(ext.isEmpty() || ext.isNull())
                qDebug() << it.fileInfo().absoluteFilePath();
            else
                if(parameters.contains(ext))
                {
                    k++;
                    qDebug() << directory.toLatin1();
                    m_files.append(directory.toLatin1());
                }
        }
    } while (it.hasNext());
    qdebug() << "Escaneados " j << " ficheros.";
    qdebug() << "Registrados " j << " ficheros.";
}
```

La salida del programa me muestra los caracteres acentuados sustituidos por un signo de interrogación **?** y eso me hace imposible procesar los ficheros posteriormente mostrándome un error de :

> Ruta no válida. fichero no encontrado

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto??

Comment: Que tal si pruebas con quitar el toLatin1().

Comment: Si creo que ya con eso se resuelve el problema por el momento. Gracias